# WIndows Server + Java Runtime Install: What old JRE.. folders can I delete?

Tags: windows-server-2003, java

We have a windows server that has been running for a few years, it has the Java runtime installed, which is purely used for the Dell software. Over the years various updates have been applied filling up the c:\ drive. the updates are about 200Mb each, and there seem to be a few jre.. folder in the Program File/Java folder. Can I delete some of the older ones? any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, yes.  If you want to make sure this is done safely, you can use the tool [JavaRa](http://raproducts.org/javara.html).